# Minimalistic C# WinForms application?

Tags: c#, winforms

**I need example of simplest possible WinForms application in C#.**

It's for educational purposes (for better understanding what Visual Studio really does, and what is required to make WinForms work).

Initially I had idea to just analyse Visual Studio generated code, remove unecessary parts, and merge everything into one file and try to compile it with `csc.exe`. However my knowledge about C# and .NET is not enough to determine what is really necessary, and what is not, do I need own Dispose method etc. I don't want to experiment.

Additionally - VS generated code contains variables an methods commented like this: "Required designer variable.", or "Required method for Designer support".

So far, I prepared this code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Minimalism
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread] // 1. its necessary? what it is this?
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles(); // 2. can i get rid of this?
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); // 3. and this?
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }

    class Form1 : Form
    {
        // how to make minimalistic constructor for form with 1 textbox?
        // do I need to write that constructor? there should be one in Form class...
    }
```

Can you help me to finish this, and explain these 3 things from my comments in code?

Answer (score 3):

1. is only important if you are doing COM interop. You're not.
2. makes your application look like the platform it runs on, which means it will make your application look like the Windows XP style on Windows XP, and like the Windows 7 style on Windows 7.
3. tells your GDI+ stuff to use GDI instead.

In short: all of these 3 lines are optional. I would keep number 2 though, so your application does not look like dated cheese.

Comment: Thanks. Now i just need that constructor and textbox...

Comment: public partial class Form1 : Form, will be needed as well. You will also need to call: InitializeComponent();